# jQuery - Push each recorded audio files from rows to input fields in rows of the table respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

1. I have a table below with 2 rows but it can be doubled with a button (Add another Word media) and only one submit button for all rows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="form-row dynamic-medias" id="medias-0">
        <td class="field-path_to_file">
            <div id="medias-0-path_to_file_with_media_recorder">
                <div class="py-2">
                    <input type="file" name="medias-0-path_to_file" class="bg-slate-100 p-2"
                        id="id_medias-0-path_to_file">
                </div>

                <p>
                    Or record an audio
                </p>

                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button id="medias-0-path_to_file_record_start" type="button"
                        class="px-2 py-1 text-white bg-green-500 disabled:bg-gray-500 rounded-sm"
                        onclick="startRecording(this)">
                        Record
                    </button>
                    <button id="medias-0-path_to_file_record_stop" type="button"
                        class="px-2 py-1 text-white bg-red-500 disabled:bg-gray-500 disabled:text-gray-200 rounded-sm"
                        onclick="stopRecording(this)" disabled="">
                        Stop
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="recording" id="medias-0-path_to_file-record-status">
                    <span class="text-sm">
                        Click the "Start Recording" button to start recording
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <audio controls="" src="blob:http://localhost:8000/79977bf5-155b-4ca1-b5bc-097b8a55a80a"></audio><a
                download="Recorded-Media"
                href="blob:http://localhost:8000/79977bf5-155b-4ca1-b5bc-097b8a55a80a">Download it!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="form-row dynamic-medias" id="medias-1">
        <td class="field-path_to_file">
            <div id="medias-1-path_to_file_with_media_recorder">
                <div class="py-2">
                    <input type="file" name="medias-1-path_to_file" class="bg-slate-100 p-2"
                        id="id_medias-1-path_to_file">
                </div>
                <p>
                    Or record an audio
                </p>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button id="medias-1-path_to_file_record_start" type="button"
                        class="px-2 py-1 text-white bg-green-500 disabled:bg-gray-500 rounded-sm"
                        onclick="startRecording(this)">
                        Record
                    </button>
                    <button id="medias-1-path_to_file_record_stop" type="button"
                        class="px-2 py-1 text-white bg-red-500 disabled:bg-gray-500 disabled:text-gray-200 rounded-sm"
                        onclick="stopRecording(this)" disabled="">
                        Stop
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="recording" id="medias-1-path_to_file-record-status">
                    <span class="text-sm">
                        Click the "Start Recording" button to start recording
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <audio controls="" src="blob:http://localhost:8000/cd165412-b186-4a11-8fd7-6997750b9bd3"></audio><a
                download="Recorded-Media"
                href="blob:http://localhost:8000/cd165412-b186-4a11-8fd7-6997750b9bd3">Download it!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="add-row">
        <td colspan="4"><a href="#">Add another Word media</a></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

2. Below is a jQuery script that gets the recorded audio from a small audio player for each line and moves it to an input type="file" field when the submit button is clicked. (By the way, this is a Django admin panel form)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(async function(e) {
        let url = $('audio').attr('src')
        if(url != undefined){
            const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
   
            let file = await fetch(url)
                    .then(r => r.blob())
                    .then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], "user_recording.mp3", { type: "mp3" }))

            const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);
            fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
        }
        $('#word_form').submit()
    });
});
```

The problem is the jQuery script only works for the first and one line.
Can anyone help me change the above script work for each line with loop (each line has its own audio tag)? and There is only one submit button for all rows. Sorry for my english (it's not my native language :) )

Comment: do you want to run your function for each row by clicking only one Submit button ?
If Yes so for that you have to use loop

Comment: You haven't provided the relevant code for an exact reason.  It could be 1)`input[type=submit]` is created after doc ready - likely as you state "can be doubled"/"add word" so maybe you're adding another submit button - your code will only work for the first, not new buttons   2) you have more than one `id=word_form` - your code will work for the first, not 2nd+ or new forms - IDs must be unique  3) `$('audio').attr('src')` will only give you the `src` of the first `<audio>` element - you need additional selectors/a loop etc to access others (depending whether there's one submit or more)

Comment: Amit Singh and freedomn-m I have only one submit button for all rows, even if I double the rows it will only be one submit button, could you help me write a loop for it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Amit Singh and freedomn-m's comments that give an idea for looping it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(async function(e) {
      let url = $('audio').each(function(){
      });

      for (i=0; i<url.length; i++) {
        new_url = url[i].getAttribute("src");
        if (new_url != undefined){
          const fileInput = document.getElementById('id_medias-'+i+'-path_to_file');
          let file = await fetch(new_url).then(r => r.blob()).then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], "user_recording.mp3", { type: "mp3" }))

          const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
          dataTransfer.items.add(file);
          fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
        } 
      }
      $('#word_form').submit()
    });
});
```